# Variable in dictionary

Tags: python

I want to replace `CHANGE` with the variable `zone_list`.

```py
output_zones = {'CHANGE' : {}}
```

I would like to get:

```py
{'zone_name': {... a set of dictionaries...}}
```

What is the correct syntax? This code is wrong:

```py
zone_list = zone_name
output_zones = {f"{zone_list}:", {}}
output_zones[zone_list].update(zone_info)
```

Comment: `output_zones[zone_name] = output_zones.pop('CHANGE')`? Or are you talking about the name of the variable? I would discourage against the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
output_zones = {'{}'.format(zone_list): {}}
```

Comment: If `zone_list` is a string, this is doing the exact same thing as `output_zones = {zone_list: {}}` would without the additional level of indirection.

Comment: Thanks to all. Both syntax works.